# How to check if next input is empty?

Tags: c, input, io, stream

I'm trying to redirect a file as stdin input (one of the requirements). I can't figure out how to check if the next input is empty or if it's done.

something like this

```
./a.out program < file.txt
```

So here is what I am trying to do.

```
char string[10];

while ( the input is NOT empty)
{
    scanf("%s",&string);
    printf("%s",string);
}
```

The given file looks something like this

```
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the following, it will only stop when `scanf` cannot read anything else.

```
while( scanf("%s", string) != EOF ){
    printf("%s", string);

}
```

**By the way** to scan a string we cannot make use of `&` as it already is a pointer.

Comment: I coded like this as well. The man page for scanf informs : "The value EOF is
     returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-
     of-file occurs."

Comment: Thanks alot, that did the trick. I don't have access to man pages on my terminal since my school blocked it for an exam and hasnt unblocked it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`feof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/feof.html) on `stdin`:

```
while (!feof(stdin)) {
    scanf("%s", string); // You do not need & for strings
    printf("%s",string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I tried the one above and this one. Both of them work.

Comment: @user1993422 You are welcome! If your problem is solved, consider accepting one of the solutions to indicate that you are not actively looking for an improved solution, and to earn a new badge on stack overflow.